# Cloudfront Logs into Prometheus

Tags: logstash, amazon-cloudfront, prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to collect AWS cloudfront request level metrics [count of request by unique resource] into Prometheus.
I've seen how to use Logstash to forward the logs to ElasticSearch, and I thought of polling/querying ElasticSearch once a minute to get an aggregate, then exporting that result to Prometheus.

But it feels a little sloppy considering potential timing issues or missing/duplicate metric values.

I also saw a metrics filter for Logstash - so maybe I could create a meter for each unique url, then use the http output plugin to send the metrics to Prometheus.

One more thought -
I've never used CloudFront with CloudWatch. Maybe I could use the CloudWatch exporter for Prometheus if it provide request counts at the resource level, or is it higher level aggregates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cloudwatch_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter) to scrape metrics from cloudwatch for CloudFront.

Comment: Thanks @Praveen - Does that include request level metrics? From the documentation I read, it only shows summary data. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitoring-using-cloudwatch.html